# Do interfaces with struct properties result in boxing?

Tags: c#, clr, boxing

Let's say I have some struct and some interface which, among other things, exposes that struct as a property:

```
public struct MyStruct{
    public readonly string Hello;

    public MyStruct(string world){
        Hello = world;
    }
}

public interface IMyInterface{
    MyStruct myStruct{ get; set; }
}
```

And within my application, an object which implements that interface is created and passed into some method:

```
public void MyMethod(IMyInterface interface){
    var structContents = interface.myStruct;
    Console.WriteLine(structContents.Hello);
}
```

My question is: when I'm packing that struct value into the interface and passing it around my application, is that struct being boxed and then being unboxed later when I access it in MyMethod? Or is there any other boxing/unboxing or other issue going on behind the scenes with such a design?

Comment: No, structs as members of interfaces are not boxed. Structs assigned to a variable of an interface type they implement are boxed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yz2be5wk.aspx):

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type **object** or to any interface type implemented by this value type.

You're not doing either of those things with `myStruct`, so there's no boxing here.

Comment: Great, that's what I thought. Thanks!